# How to enable CORS for a single website for my REST API in AppEngine

Tags: rest, api, google-cloud-platform, cors, yaml

I have an API in Appengine in a flexible environment. It does not support CORS. I believe it is because it doesn't support it by default

```
After ESP 1.0 is released on January 2, 2017, all Flexible Environment API deployments will feature the new version of ESP and will automatically disallow CORS requests by default. App Engine applications are automatically redeployed every 7 days, so sometime in the 7 days following the release of ESP 1.0, your app will be restarted with the latest version and will automatically be protected from unintended cross origin sharing.

If you are using Flexible Environments and would like to continue to allow CORS requests, you must add the "x-google-endpoints" snippet above to your API configuration (aka OpenAPI specification aka Swagger file). If you are relying on CORS, we recommend that you add the snippet as soon as possible and redeploy your service using the following command to avoid service interruption. Then you will not see changed behavior when the new version of ESP rolls out.
```

This page tells me to set allowCors = True and implement support in my backend code (do they mean my main.go?)
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions

This page tell me to add some code to my ESP, but I'm not sure where it means - in my openapi swagger file?
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-proxy-startup-options#adding_cors_support_to_esp

This page https://enable-cors.org/server_appengine.html
tells me to add this code, I assume to my main.go, but what does it mean?

```
func doGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/csv")
  fmt.Fprintf(w, csvData)
}
```

I am struggling to find straight forward steps to enable CORS support for one website on my AppEngine API. Can someone support please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way to achieve it is to add the `x-google-extension` at the top level of your OpenAPI document:

```
swagger: "2.0"
host: "my-cool-api.endpoints.my-project-id.cloud.goog"
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "my-cool-api.endpoints.my-project-id.cloud.goog"
  allowCors: True
```

There's more information regarding that in the first [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#configuring_to_allow_cors_requests) you found.

Regarding your question:

> This page https://enable-cors.org/server_appengine.html tells me to add this code, I assume to my main.go, but what does it mean?

```
func doGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/csv")
  fmt.Fprintf(w, csvData)
  }
```

That piece of code what will do is add the CORS headers whenever a GET request is received.

## EDIT:

Just to clarify, enabling CORS in Cloud Endpoints will only allow the request to hit your backend, but you have to handle the access restriction in your backend code.

As you want to restrict the CORS to only one webpage, the code will then look like:

```
func doGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.example.com")
      w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/csv")
      fmt.Fprintf(w, csvData)
      }
```

With this example, only the website https://www.example.com will be allowed.

Comment: Thanks. It allows CORS, but I don't want every website enabled, just one website - how do i specify one website?

Comment: I have edited my answer, hope you find it clearer and helps you solve your issue!

Comment: Thanks when you say backend code, do you mean I add this function to my main.go and where within. Do i add it in func main, my query handler func, or not within any func? What the the content-type text/csv bit mean and fmt.Fprintf(w, csvData). I am not using anything to do with a csv

Comment: Yes I mean to your main.go file. You have to add it in the function you are using to handle the requests, a doGet function. The content-type and fmt.Fprint are just samples from the webpage, you need to adapt the function to what do you want to achieve. The only line from the sample you really need is: `w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.example.com")`

Comment: Ok, I think it's within queryHandler, so I will try this! I'm guessing the CSV bit is a format for the cors header in the same way I've got  w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json") for the json response

Comment: Ok awesome, thank you! will let you know if it works

Comment: You are welcome, will be waiting to see if that worked out for you!

Comment: Sorry - does it have to be a function? can I just add w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.example.com") within my query handler func? My query handler func alreafy takes in those two variables w and r : func queryHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)

Comment: Glad to hear that you managed to make it work! Just approve my answer if you feel like it, so other members from the community can make use of this same sllution :)